# Please explain this behavior of Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following code:

```
# Case 1
a = dict()
b = dict()

a = {'name': 'Bob'}
b['0'] = a 

print("Initial a: ", a)
print("Initial b:", b)
print("")

a['name']  = 'Lucy'
print("Intermediate a: ", a)
print("Intermediate b: ", b)
print("")
```

We get our output:

```
Initial a: {'name': 'Bob'}
Initial b: {'0': {'name': 'Bob'}} 

Intermediate a: {'name': 'Lucy'}
Intermediate b: {'0': {'name': 'Lucy'}}
```

So changing the value of 'a', changes 'b' as well. I believe this is due to the mutable character of the dictionary.

Now, consider this snippet:

```
# Case 2
a = dict()
b = dict()

a = {'name': 'Bob'}
b['0'] = a 

print("Initial a: ", a)
print("Initial b:", b)
print("")

a = dict()
print("Intermediate a: ", a)
print("Intermediate b", b)
print("")
```

The output is:

```
Initial a: {'name': 'Bob'}
Initial b: {'0': {'name': 'Bob'}} 

Intermediate a: {}
Intermediate b: {'0': {'name': 'Bob'}}
```

Why doesn't intermediate b value become an empty dictionary for key 0 for # case 2?

Comment: Mutating one object and assigning a new object to a name are different things…

Comment: Variables, dictionaries,... only store references to objects. In first case you have two references to the same dictionary, in second case the references point to different dicts.

Comment: first case, they take same position of memory. Second case, you create a new position for a, and b still at old position, so nothing changed for b

Comment: You can use ``id`` to see it ``print(id(a), print(id(b['0'])))`` & you will both are pointing to same object ref in case 1 & for second case it is initialized with new object.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a new dictionary to `a`, it is a new independent object, and `a` loses the reference to its old value. This reference is still kept as member of `b`.

For me it is more surprising how `Bob` turns into `Lucy` in your second snipplet. :-D

Comment: Thanks for catching my error! Edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess dr. v has answered your question but an extra information tip is when you want to easily copy an object in python you can use [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) built-in module:

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = {'hamed': 12, 'dr.v': 20}
b = deepcopy(a)
a['new'] = 'is this in b too?'
print(f'a is ({a}) b is ({b})
```

and the output is:

> a is ({'hamed': 12, 'dr.v': 20, 'new': 'is this in b too?'}) b is ({'hamed': 12, 'dr.v': 20})

Answer (score 1):

In the first case "a" and b ['0'] point to the same memory address so when you make a change to "a" it also affects b ["0"]
In case two, when you assign a new dictionary to the variable "a", you do not overwrite the memory address that houses the old dictionary (also pointed by b [0]).  Variable a now points to a new memory address that contains the new dictionary, the old one if not pointed to by any variable would be removed from memory but being pointed to by b [0] remains intact

Answer (score 1):

Here is an illustration from a Python REPL session.

```
In [1]: a = {1: 2}       # A couple of dicts similar to your example.
In [2]: b = {0: a}

In [3]: id(a)            # Every object in a Python program has a unique ID.
Out[3]: 4442001056

In [4]: id(b[0])         # Note that both `a` and `b[0]` refer to the same object.
Out[4]: 4442001056

                         # Variable names are like labels. You can attach multiple
                         # labels to the same underlying object. We already have
                         # two ways to refer to object 4442001056: using `a` or `b[0]`.

In [5]: x = a            # Let's add another way.
In [6]: id(x)            # Again it's the same underlying object.
Out[6]: 4442001056

In [7]: a[77] = 77       # Let's modify object 4442001056 in various ways.
In [8]: b[0][88] = 88
In [9]: x[99] = 99

                         # The changes are reflected everywhere.

In [10]: a
Out[10]: {1: 2, 77: 77, 88: 88, 99: 99}

In [11]: b
Out[11]: {0: {1: 2, 77: 77, 88: 88, 99: 99}}

In [12]: x
Out[12]: {1: 2, 77: 77, 88: 88, 99: 99}

                         # Now let's attach the label `a` to a different object --
                         # in this case object 4427016088.

In [13]: a = {'hello': 'world'}
In [14]: id(a)
Out[14]: 4427016088

                         # Nothing happens to object 4442001056.

In [15]: b
Out[15]: {0: {1: 2, 77: 77, 88: 88, 99: 99}}

In [16]: x
Out[16]: {1: 2, 77: 77, 88: 88, 99: 99}
```

Also see Ned Batchelder's piece on Python [names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out the code using http://www.pythontutor.com/

you'll see that by creating `a` new dict in case #2 python keeps the current pointer of `b` at the same memory location but allocates `a` to a new location in memory,
since `b` is still pointing at the old memory location, when changing `a`, it does not affect `b`.